# MSDeploy when IIS application pool is down

Tags: iis-7.5, msdeploy

If I shut down the application pool of the site in IIS 7.5 first, can I still use MSDeploy to deploy web code to this site?

The basic command is to execute `C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe -source:package='......zip' -dest:auto,includeAcls='False'` locally on the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can still deploy a site with MSDeploy if the AppPool is stopped.